# Any module to start, shutdown Java process (like Jetty start.jar)?

Tags: java, startup, lifecycle, shutdown-hook

Most servers like `Jetty` or `Weblogic` provide some sort of mechanism to start or shutdown the server via a call (sometimes over `jmx`).  Can always to keep stuff running from main:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
     Setup Spring context.....

     Object lock = new Object();
     synchronized (lock) {
          lock.wait();  
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

And do a kill on the process PID.  But thought there might a nice open-source solution hanging around in cyber space that adds `JMX` bells and whistles.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to start by looking at a combination of [Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/) and [Commons Launcher](http://commons.apache.org/launcher/).  Not sure if there are any JMX bells and whistles in there, but this provides hooks into your OS management interface for server processes.